# .Net class library compilation error on build machine

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, .net-standard, csproj, dotnet-sdk

I have a SDK styled .Net class library which compiles properly on my local machine, however fails on build server.

The contents of .csproj are

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net35;net40;netstandard1.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <Version>1.5.6</Version>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

The error displayed is:
NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Standard 4.0. Either target .NET Standard 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Standard 4.0

I have .NET Core 3.1.113 installed on build server and .NET 5 installed on local machine.

Note: If I remove `netstandard1.0` from TargetFrameworks then build succeeds on both the machines. However I want my library to target .net standard 1.0 as well.

I cannot understand why v4.0 is treated as .NET Standard 4.0 on build server. Can anyone let me know what the problem might be?

Comment: How did you build your project on build machine? Dotnet build or any other? Could you please share the build command line with us?

Comment: I am using msbuild that gets shipped with visual studio 2019 and passing in the project name as parameter. The msbuild tool is located at : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin

Comment: Sure. If that situation, you should check your VS 2019 in the vs installer, modify it, and check if you install all the sdks on that.

Comment: If I remove the <TargetFrameworkVersion> attribute, then it is working. However, I cannot remove it because my build server is configured in a way that it always looks for <TargetFrameworkVersion> in csproj file. Any idea what the value will be for <TargetFrameworkVersion> if target frameworks are 3 as listed in question?Also the purpose of  it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remove** the following line from your `.csproj` file:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

This overrides the version value that the SDK infers from `TargetFramework` which will interfere with your definition of `net3.5` and so on - you were actually building .NET Framework 4.0 twice and then override `netstandard1.0` to .NET Standard (inferred `TargetFrameworkIdentifier`) to 4.0. Newer versions of the SDK may have different inference logic which may be a difference between 3.1 and 5.0 SDKs but this is an error in the csproj nonetheless.

If your build logic relies on `TargetFrameworkVersion` being defined in the project I suggest you try to change your build logic - this is VERY DANGEROUS to have in a modern csproj file where you rely on `TargetFramework` and `TargetFrameworks` (plural). You can also try to move it into a separate `<PropertyGroup>` with an always-fals-condition (e.g. `<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(ThisIsToWorkAroundBuildScripts)' == 'True'">`)

Comment: Thank you, this answer provided lot of insight into what I was trying to understand. Rather than moving TargetFrameworkVersion into an always false condition, I used the following: <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net40'">
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net35'">
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='netstandard1.0'">
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v1.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

Answer (score -1):

> I cannot understand why v4.0 is treated as .NET Standard 4.0 on build
> server. Can anyone let me know what the problem might be?

That is quite strange and I have not seen that issue before. And there is no info about `.NET Standard 4.0` and I did not know why VS treats `v4.0`(net framework 4.0) as `net standard 4.0`. Maybe your there is some problems about your server environment.

Please follow these:

**1)** First, please use `dotnet --list-sdks` under CMD to check if you installed `net core 2.1` sdk or any other versions. And actually, net core 2.1 sdk could support the previous sdks including `net standard 1.0`. Maybe you would better install [net core 2.1 sdk](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/2.1). Also, you could install the latest **Net Core 3.1 Sdk**.

**2)** check system environment variable, and find whether there is a variable called `MSBuildSDKsPath`, if so, please delete it. Then, restart.

**3)** delete `bin` and `obj` folder under the build server. Also, I suggest you would better use Build Tool for VS to build your projects on the server rather than `dotnet build`. `dotnet cli` does not contain the tool for net framework. What's more, your project is multi-targetframeworks, it could build `net core` and `net standard`, and also you have to download net framework sdk.

That is too complex, you could install [the Build Tool for VS2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019)(more likely a lightweight cmd which integrates dotnet, net framework, all vs environment). Also, install the **Net desktop build tool** and **net core build tool** workload, also install the related sdks.

[image]

**When** you finish it, delete `bin` and `obj` folder, type this under Build Tool for VS command:

```
msbuild xxx\xxx.csproj -t:clean,restore,build
```